# Separate city, time, hours from string

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, text, beautifulsoup

I'm having response from beautiful soup scrapper in string like below

```
1:25Allahabad01 h 50 m Non stop13:15Pune
12:40Allahabad07 h 25 m 1 stop via New Delhi20:05Pune
```

Looking for a way to split it into expected output:

> ['1:25', 'Allahabad', '01 h 50 m', 'Non stop', '13:15', 'Pune']
> ['12:40', 'Allahabad', '07 h 25 m', '1 stop via New Delhi', '20:05', 'Pune']

City names can be different, I'm thinking of regex but I'm not good in that so looking for some better approaches to do this.

Code how I'm getting these values is

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
url = "https://www.makemytrip.com/flight/search?itinerary=IXD-PNQ-14/07/2022&tripType=O&paxType=A-2_C-0_I-0&intl=false&cabinClass=E&ccde=IN&lang=eng"
driver.get(url)
body = driver.page_source
driver.quit()  # Browser Closed.
soupBody = BeautifulSoup(body)  # Parse the inner HTML using BeautifulSoup
for el in soupBody.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'timingOptionOuter'}):
    print(el.get_text())
```

Comment: Could you provide some code to clarify how you get that texts please, cause I assume there is a better way of scraping, so you do not have to modify in postprocessing. thanks

Comment: @HedgeHog Updated my code with required code

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @HedgeHog, that the issue is the parsing with BS4.

Here's a solution anyway:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = re.compile(r"(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})([A-Za-z ]+)((?:\d{1,2} h )?\d{1,2} m) (Non stop|\d+ stop[A-Za-z ]+)(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})([A-Za-z ]+)")
>>> regex.findall("1:25Allahabad01 h 50 m Non stop13:15Pune\n12:40Allahabad07 h 25 m 1 stop via New Delhi20:05Pune")
[('1:25', 'Allahabad', '01 h 50 m', 'Non stop', '13:15', 'Pune'), ('12:40', 'Allahabad', '07 h 25 m', '1 stop via New Delhi', '20:05', 'Pune')]
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned there is no need for regex or any post-processing - scraping the text via [`get_text()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) you could set additional parameter to join / separate the strings:

```
el.get_text(',', strip=True)
```

**Note:** *In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names) - Site is not aivailable from Europe so this is just a general approach how to fix your issue.*